# Anime about a girl who is a zombie

Tags: story-identification, anime

It is an anime. I can't recall if it was a series of a film. A group of students broke into what I assume was a museum (there was a lot of historical artifacts) but they end up waking up a zombie/mummy girl who then starts hunting them down.

I can't recall if there was another girl who was dressed as a French maid (because anime) but I might be getting another anime mixed up with that one.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was the zombie/mummy wrapped in bandages?